# Dgrid subrows do not appear even though they are defined

Tags: dojo, dgrid

```
this.grid = new CustomGrid({
                    collection: this.store,
                    subRows: [
                        [
                            { field: 'first', label: 'First', rowSpan: 2 },
                            { field: 'last', label: 'Last', rowSpan: 2 },
                            { field: 'bats', label: 'Bats', rowSpan: 2 },
                            { field: 'throws', label: 'Throws', rowSpan: 2 },
                            { field: 'totalG', label: 'G' },
                            { field: 'totalAB', label: 'AB' },
                            { field: 'totalR', label: 'R' },
                            { field: 'totalRBI', label: 'RBI' },
                            { field: 'totalBB', label: 'BB' },
                            { field: 'totalK', label: 'K' }
                        ],
                        [
                            { field: 'totalGAB', label: 'Games as Batter', colSpan: 2 },
                            { field: 'totalH', label: 'H' },
                            { field: 'total2B', label: '2B' },
                            { field: 'total3B', label: '3B' },
                            { field: 'totalHR', label: 'HR' }
                        ]
                    ],
                    showHeader: true,
                    className: 'dgrid-autoheight',
                    showFooter: false,
                    selectionMode: "none",
                    loadingMessage: "Loading form...",
                    noDataMessage: "No Skill in this form"

         });
```

I am using the above code for creating a dgrid.I have loaded the dojo.css,claro.css and dgrid.css in my base html.But for some reason the subrows are not rendered on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that it is a silly mistake and here it is:

```
collection: this.store
```

In that context, `this` refers to the `CustomGrid` object. You probably already have the store loaded before and it is stored in a property in another context (the one that instantiates the grid). If you are not loading your store, there is no way to render the data, since it would not be there for the grid.

So, basically, the simple fix is:

```
var self = this;
this.grid = new CustomGrid({
    collection: self.store
    // all other grid properties
});
```

Hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank but this is not the reason. The problem was the order in which the extension for the dgrid was defined.